# Python save images with open CV to an array in a sorted way according to the image name

Tags: python

I have 50.000 in a folder that have names "1.png" to "50000.png". And I want to save them to some array in spesicfic order, because I have labels for them in order to classify them. So when order of the images get messed up, labels become useless. (i.e: 1.png will be saved to first index and 2.png will be saved to second index etc.). I try this code for this purpose:

```
#Read and save all Images to images array. 
images=[]
image_folder=[img for img in glob.glob("C:/Users/yazilim1/Desktop/Jupyter/cifar-10/train/*.png")]
image_folder.sort()
for image in image_folder:
    images.append(cv2.imread(image))
    print(image)
print("Number of Images added:" + str(len(images)))
```

However, print(image) output looks like this:
[image: print(image]

How can I achive to save that images to "images" array with order?

Comment: Why you don't use `dict`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is in order though.

Since `image_folder` is a list of *strings*, `image_folder.sort()` will perform *lexicographical sorting*, where `"1" < "10" < "100" < "1000" < "1001" < ... < "2" < "20"` and so on.

If you want to treat `"100.png"` like "integer 100 + file extension", do this:

```
image_folder.sort(key=lambda file_name: int(file_name.split('.')[0]))
```